# typedef with templates

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

```
template<class T> struct A {
    typedef int Int;
    A::Int b; // Line 1 (fails)
    Int c; // Line 2 (compiles)
};

int main(){    
   A<int> x;
   x.c = 13;
}
```

Errors

```
error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘Int’ with no type
error: extra qualification ‘A<T>::’ on member ‘Int’
error: expected ‘;’ before ‘b’
```

Line 1 fails but Line 2 compiles. Why?

Comment: Your code compiles on g++ 4.4.5 with -Wall, what error message are you getting?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need a `typename`

```
typename A::Int b;
```

The `typename` keyword is required because the member is referred to using a qualified name `A::Int`.

`Int c` is fine because no qualified name is used in that case.

14.6/6

> Within the definition of a class template or within the definition of a member of a class template, the keyword *typename* is not required when referring to the unqualified name of a previously declared member
>     of the class template that declares a type. The keyword *typename* **shall always be specified when the
>     member is referred to using a qualified name**, even if the qualifier is simply the class template name.

Comment: stick typename on things solves EVERYTHING. Seriously you need typename before qualified dependent types ( read http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~driscoll/typename.html )

Comment: How is `A::Int` a dependent type?  It doesn't vary based on T.

Comment: @Chris : Its is not a dependent type. Its a fully qualified name for `Int`.

Comment: @Prasoon, sorry, I should have put @George on my comment, since I was referring to his comment.

Comment: @Prasoon: Its a dependent type. `A::Int` is `A<T>::int`. Inside class, the type argument is implicit.

Comment: @Chris that's a correct observation. This is fixed in C++0x, which makes the name `A::Int` nondependent, not requiring `typename` anymore.

Comment: @Johannes Schaub - litb How is A::Int a nondependent name in C++0x?

Comment: @vij http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#224 (those paragraphs changed quite a bit compared to the FDIS, but #224 captures the basic gist).